# Add header over one column in grid (Vaadin)

Tags: java, header, grid, vaadin

I am trying to **joining** `columns` in `grid header`. But the one feature for me is missing.
I have created the `grid` for employees which are **divided** into the specific **departments**, but there are employees, which **are in department alone**.

`Vaadin grid` **does not allow** add `header` **over one** `column`.

So the result should looks like:

[image]

Is there any solution how can I do this even though `Vaadin` **doesn't allow it** directly?

Because if I tried it, it throws an exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.application.views.dashboard.DashboardView': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.application.views.dashboard.DashboardView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot join less than 2 cells
```

My code:

```
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>(Person.class, false);
Grid.Column<Person> john = grid.addColumn(..).setHeader("John");
Grid.Column<Person> fred = grid.addColumn(..).setHeader("Fred");
Grid.Column<Person> marcus = grid.addColumn(..).setHeader("Marcus");
Grid.Column<Person> adam = grid.addColumn(..).setHeader("Adam");
Grid.Column<Person> peter = grid.addColumn(..).setHeader("Peter");
Grid.Column<Person> eve = grid.addColumn(..).setHeader("Eve");

HeaderRow headerRow = grid.prependHeaderRow();
headerRow.join(john, fred).setText("engineers");
headerRow.join(marcus, adam, peter).setText("economists");
headerRow.join(eve).setText("charwoman"); //this is problematic row
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of joining columns is actually that.  If you just want to put
text in a prepended header row, get the cell for that column and set the
text or the component on it.

```
new Grid<Map>(Map, false).tap {
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].each { c ->
        addColumn({ it.get(c) }).setKey(c).setHeader(c)
    }
    prependHeaderRow().tap {
        getCell(getColumnByKey('a')).setText('A')
        join(
            getColumnByKey('b'), 
            getColumnByKey('c')
        ).setText('B&C')
        getCell(getColumnByKey('d')).setText('D')
    }
    setItems([[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3],])
}
```